# On which physical drive is this logical drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, logical-drive

I want to understand where logical drives (e.g. `C:`, `D:`) are mapped on physical drives (e.g. I have a Western Digital and a Toshiba physical disks connected to my laptop).

On Linux, I would do something like:

```
lsblk
```

to see the filesystem layout.  Then

```
ls -lh /dev/disk/by-id
```

to see how filesystems are mapped to physical devices (the ID's usually have the name of the device in them).

---

How can I achieve something similar in MS Windows?  I tried looking in Control Panel → Device Manager, but there's no useful info there. Not in the properties of logical drives either.  Googling found me the `wmic` utility, but either I don't understand its output or the information isn't there.

Comment: Please open CMD, and type diskpart, then https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: @dExIT It's really hard to get `diskpart` to print anything at all. It also resists interactive usage attempts (it tries to open in a separate graphical window, which it then immediately closes). I tried putting it in a foo.bat file followed by `pause` command, but it just doesn't display any output whatsover.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The easiest and most obvious way would be to use Computer Management.

Computer Management is located through *Start* > *Control Panel* > *Administrative Tools* > *Computer Management*

From here, find *Storage* > *Disk Management*

Alternatively, you can type `diskmgmt.msc` in the Run Dialog or from a Command Prompt.

Diskmanagement gives you the information you requested. All drives, with their partitions, and how they are partitioned.

At the bottom of Disk Management, you'll find a graphical overview of the disks. Rightclicking a disk and choosing properties gives you the information for that specific disk.

If you seek a commandline tool that works similar, then *diskpart* is what you're after.

Comment: Close, but not really. It doesn't say anywhere what's the disk name. The only way I see how I can distinguish between different disk is by their size, which isn't enough information to figure out which disks are those.

Comment: @wvxvw I've edited my post to give you the information you seek.

Comment: You can also run `diskmgmt.msc` from Start => Run or Command Prompt to open Disk Management directly.

Comment: Why the "\[EDIT\]" tag? You know bb-codes don't work here. I'm confused.

Comment: I edited text in between, and this seemed to be the best way to clarify what I added

Comment: You can also very quickly and easily access Disk Management by pressing Windows+X o open a handy menu with a number of links to power options.

Comment: Also it worth noting, you should right click disk handle itself, not a partition on it.

Answer (score 16):

WMIC answer:

```
C:\> wmic diskdrive get index,caption
Caption                    Index
SAMSUNG HD103SJ            1
C300-CTFDDAC128MAG         2
Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB  0

C:\> wmic partition get name,diskindex,index,size
DiskIndex  Index  Name                   Size
1          0      Disk #1, Partition #0  1000202043392
2          0      Disk #2, Partition #0  128033226752
0          0      Disk #0, Partition #0  104857600
0          1      Disk #0, Partition #1  499529023488
0          2      Disk #0, Partition #2  471859200
```

The "DiskIndex" values from the second command line up with the "Index" values from the first command. So you can see that disks 1 and 2 each have a single partition, while disk 0 "Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB" has three partitions: two small recovery ones and the main system partition.

Mapping the volumes (C:) etc to partitions seems to be impossible without powershell.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822559/powershell-and-wmi-how-to-map-logical-disk-volumes-to-a-hard-disk-or-vice-versa

Answer (score 12):

You can use PowerShell!

To get the info on a drive from a single partition's drive letter:

```
Get-Disk (Get-Partition -DriveLetter 'C').DiskNumber
```

It produces output like this:

```
Number Friendly Name Serial Number                    HealthStatus         OperationalStatus      Total Size Partition
                                                                                                             Style
------ ------------- -------------                    ------------         -----------------      ---------- ----------
0      WDC WD7500...      <redacted>                  Healthy              Online                  698.64 GB GPT
```

You can tack on a `| Format-List` to the original command to get an easier-to-read result with more info:

```
UniqueId           : <redacted>
Number             : 0
Path               : \\?\scsi<redacted>
Manufacturer       :
Model              : WDC WD7500BPVX-60JC3T0
SerialNumber       :      <redacted>
Size               : 698.64 GB
AllocatedSize      : 750151131136
LogicalSectorSize  : 512
PhysicalSectorSize : 4096
NumberOfPartitions : 6
PartitionStyle     : GPT
IsReadOnly         : False
IsSystem           : True
IsBoot             : True
```

To get some info on the drive of each partition:

```
Get-Partition | % {New-Object PSObject -Property @{'PartitionNumber'=$_.PartitionNumber; 'DiskNumber'=$_.DiskNumber; 'DiskModel'=(Get-Disk $_.DiskNumber).Model; 'PartitionSize'=$_.Size; 'DriveLetter'=$_.DriveLetter}}
```

It produces a collection of PowerShell objects that you can use like those you get out of real cmdlets. When printed to the screen, its output looks like this (some partitions edited out to save vertical space):

```
DriveLetter     :
DiskNumber      : 0
DiskModel       : WDC WD7500BPVX-60JC3T0
PartitionSize   : 681574400
PartitionNumber : 1

DriveLetter     : C
DiskNumber      : 0
DiskModel       : WDC WD7500BPVX-60JC3T0
PartitionSize   : 726793488384
PartitionNumber : 4

DriveLetter     : D
DiskNumber      : 0
DiskModel       : WDC WD7500BPVX-60JC3T0
PartitionSize   : 21351104512
PartitionNumber : 6
```

Comment: +1.  `Get-Disk -Partition (Get-Partition -DriveLetter 'C')` can also be used to the same effect.

Answer (score 8):

On Windows you can use the Disk Management console.

On Windows 10 you can just right click the start button and in the list should be "Disk Management".

From there you will have a graphical view of the disks, their layout and what drive letter is assigned to each partition.

[image]

Western digital have guides for all the recent Windows operating systems at https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=1284 and this is also when I got the image above.

Answer (score 2):

Control panel -> Administrative tools -> computer management -> disk management

Answer (score 0):

You can use CrsytalDiskInfo

https://crystalmark.info/en/download/#CrystalDiskInfo

You can see immediately which partition or logic drive pertains to which physical drive.

Rapid and easy.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a native Windows solution.