# Cannot format new hard drive while installing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-installation

I just got my new hard drive (500GB) and I was about to install Windows 7, but received an error while formatting the partition (`0x80070057`—damaged disk). The disk is new and I've never used it before. I am using a Dell Inspiron 6400 laptop and I can easily install and remove the hard drive; however, I tried to install Windows XP SP3 but it didn't recognize the hard drive at all. Any advice?

Comment: Did you purchase this as a new product or a used product?

Comment: @Ramhound new, i bought it in local store (orion computers)

Comment: Given that HDD manufactures have stop producing 500 GB HDDs for awhile now, I strongly suggest, you return the product as defective.

Comment: Even new products can be defect when they're new. In technical terms, this is called a DoA (Death on Arrival). Just return it to the store where you bought it, and they'll give you a replacement.

Comment: DOA- dead on arrival is actually quite common. If you have another computer you should plug that in and run some hard drive tests on it, such as SEATools from Seagate or whatever the manufacturer is they probably have a testing suite. In fact manufacturers ask users to run the test before returning it, because a huge percentage of returned drives are actually perfectly fine.

Comment: It's conceivable that the disk uses 4096-byte logical sectors. I don't know how Windows XP handles such disks. If it has problems with them, then the disk might simply be incompatible with your old OS. That said, most external disks with 4096-byte logical sectors are 1TB or more in size, and I don't know for a fact that XP can't handle such disks. Thus, this is a bit of a long shot, but it might be worth investigating. Various disk tools will tell you the sector size; see [here.](http://superuser.com/questions/120809/how-can-i-determine-the-sector-size-on-an-external-hard-drive)

Comment: @RodSmith: Advanced Format is not the issue. Windows 7 supports AF 512e disks.

Comment: NiKoLaPrO specified Windows XP as being worse than 7 with the disk, so I was responding to that. Furthermore, I'm not talking about 512e disks, but about 4Kn disks, which have 4096-byte *logical* **and** physical sectors. Those cause problems for a lot of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result from Googling the error code is [this Microsoft Support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2476568).

Delete any existing partitions and try again. If there are no partitions on the disk, it's probably defective and should be returned.

Comment: i created 2 partitions and there was one more, for the system, however i tried to i have ndelete them and create a new ones few times but didn't helped, but i have no problem with partitions, only with formating them. Thanks for your answer, I appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ramhound @LPChip and @bwDraco suggested, I returned hard drive to the store where i bought it and I got replacement, I installed windows 7 and everything works just fine.

Thanks for support.